# sql function to get comma separated values when start and end number is given

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have start number as 5 and end number as 10. I want an sql function which gives me a  string comma separated value like (5,6,7,8,9,10).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: and what have you done to achieve your goals?

Comment: i used COALESCE but it did not work.

Comment: SQL Server does not have any built-in function for that. You need to write your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
declare @start int
declare @end int
set @start = 5;
set @end = 10;

;with ranges AS
(
    SELECT 
        @start as val
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        val + 1
    FROM   ranges
    WHERE  val+1 <= @end
)
Select distinct 
       substring((select ','+convert(varchar, ranges.val) as [text()]
                  from   ranges
                  order by 
                         ranges.val
                  for XML path ('')),2, 1000)
from   ranges
```